# PhoneGap oAuth Architecture (REST)

Tags: cordova, rest, cakephp, authentication, oauth

I have the following, which I believe is a typical setup:

1. Web application server (running on cakephp)
2. PhoneGap App, that reads/puts data from/to my web server using REST. This is built using Single Page Architecture (SPA)

Now I need to implement some authentication and allow users of my PhoneGap application to perform Social Login. While i *think* i understand the basics of oAuth in a traditional webapp / website scenario, I don't understand how it should work architecturally when a **PhoneGap app is thrown into the mix,** and I am trying to keep a REST-ful approach to all communications between PhoneGap and Web server.

My end goal is also typical that the PhoneGap app allows the user to login and communicate with the Webserver, and the Webserver keeps all user details (specific to authentication) and user created data (specific to application).

Questions arise such as:

1) Should it be the (a) PhoneGap App OR the (b) Webapplication server performing the oAuth authentication steps with the Social network (e.g. facebook)?

2) As i understand, oAuth is only used for authenticating a users identity with a 3rd party provider (e.g. facebook). Given that I also want to give users an option to **register / sign in manually** on the PhoneGap application, is my understanding correct that this **traditional sign in method does not concern oAuth**?

2) I've read some confusing articles on **Stateless Authentication** for PhoneGap applications. What is the difference between this and the opposite approach, presumably "Stateful authentication"?

3) Architecturally, how will the PhoneGap application know that it is logged in, so that the user does not have to keep logging in everytime he runs the app? Is this done via a token requested from the webserver and stored locally in the PhoneGap app?

4) PhoneGap has its own oAuth plugins. Cakephp (which powers my webserver) ALSO has its own oAuth plugins. This confuses me even further, as to which ones I need to install, this probably relates alot to Question (1).

Architectural advice and pointers very much appreciated.

Comment: I have the same questions you had. Did you find the answers?